# Trigger issue: Opportunity product is not being added automatically to the opportunity

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product

I have been trying to create this trigger and its not working. I'm not getting any errors, but an opportunity product is not being added to the opportunity automatically. I'm not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
for(OpportunityLineItem item: [
   SELECT OpportunityId, Name 
   FROM OpportunityLineItem
   WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Name = 'Car_Filter_Plus']) {
        OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = item.OpportunityId, 
            PricebookEntryId ='01uA000000QdelEIAD',
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 25)
        );
}
}
```

Ideally, here is what I need the code to do:

We have a lot of additional cost products that need to be be added to the opportunity whenever a product is added to the opportunity by the proposal team. The $ value of the additional cost needs to be a % of the product added by the proposal writer. I came across a couple codes online but have not been able to get very far. Here is one that I came across:

Proposal writer adds the following products

- CarOIL
- CarFILTER
- CarTIRE'
- CarLIGHTS

The $ value is manually added by the writer in SFDC. They put the quantity and sale price and it auto calculates

Here is what I need the code to automatically add to the opportunity

- CarOILplus
- CarFILTERplus
- CarTIREplus
- CarLIGHTSplus

The $ value of each plus product is a % of the original product, which has a dollar value entered by the writer. For example:

CarOILplus - is 5% of the $ value entered by the write when added CarOIL
CarFILTERplus - is 2% of the $ value entered by the write when added CarFILTER
CarTIREplus - is 3% of the $ value entered by the write when added CarTIRE
CarLIGHTplus - is 1% of the $ value entered by the write when added CarLIGHT
Can anyone help me? Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify OpportunityId as an attribute of line item during creation.

That's why it is not being created for any opportunities.

Here is an approach, assigning `Opportunity` from `newOpportunityLineItems.OpportunityId`:

```
trigger AUTOADDPRODUCT on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
    for (OpportunityLineItem newOpportunityLineItems: Trigger.New) { 

            OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                                        OpportunityId = newOpportunityLineItems.OpportunityId, 
                                        PricebookEntryId ='ID CODE FOR CarOILplus',
                                        Quantity = 1,
                                        UnitPrice = 25)
                                    );

    } 
    if(!OpportunityLineItems.isEmpty()){
        insert OpportunityLineItems; 
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I add that to the code?

Comment: I gave it a try but the new product is still not adding to the opportunity.

Comment: I tried again under trigger (Opportunity Product) and here is the error that I got once I tried to add the product to the oppty:
"Apex trigger Attempt1 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Attempt1: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.Attempt1: line 4, column 1 "

Comment: 'trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
    for (OpportunityLineItem newOpportunityLineItems: Trigger.New) { 
        if(newOpportunityLineItems.name.equals('Car_FILTER')){
            OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                                OpportunityId = '006g000000R2o1U', 
                                PricebookEntryId ='05uA000000UPRlcOAF',
                                Quantity = 1,
                                 UnitPrice = 25)'

Comment: I updated the code in the post. still not adding the 2nd product to the opportunity automatically.... :'(
I don't get it...

Comment: I think you have already posted a separate question and received the answer

Comment: The second product didn't get added to the opportunity automatically though... so it didn't work.

Comment: The one in the question is the code

Comment: The initial question was related to opportunity, I have answered here, for your second product creation you have raised separate question, which is not related to this one. Can you close this question. This is way your issue could be solved gradually.

Comment: sorry about that.